# JS. Как в место NaN вывести текст

Tags: javascript, html, nan

У button привязан onclick с id. 
 
В файле js я сделал сложение двух input полей, но если в эти поля ничего не вводить, 
 то в поле "Результат" выводит: NaN. 
Как можно заменить это, скажем на текст: Не введены данные / Ошибка

Comment: Пооверить что в ответе получился NaN и вывести вместо него текст. Для более детального ответа нужен код

Comment: А должен выводить или ноль, или пустую строку. Что-то не так в другом месте)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это дело можно организовать так:

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var ok = document.getElementById('ok');
var res = document.getElementById('result');

ok.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var x = a.value; 
  var y = b.value; // Это еще строки, не числа
  
  var sum = +x + +y; // Плюсик перед строкой - превращает её в число.
  
  /* Перед тем, как вывести результат - идет проверка условия
  && - значит 'И'. А NaN или пустая "" строка в логическом контексте будут false 
  Чтобы оно выплнилось, и sum не должен быть NaN, и строки не должны быть пустыми. 
  использована функция isNaN, потому что иначе 0 + 0 будет false */
  res.textContent = ( !isNaN(sum) && x && y ) ? sum : 'Введите числа!';
});
```

```html
<input id="a">
<input id="b">
<button id="ok">ok</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```